# How to get individual param from multiple params in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I want to get and display individual param from multiple params in react-router-dom like in this URL `http://localhost/tag/news/local/tour`. The URL has three params which is the last two are optional.

Here are routes and components:

```
// routes.js
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/tag/:slug/:slug1?/:slug2?" component={Archives} />
    <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage} />
</Switch>

// Component: RenderTags.js
const RenderTags = props => {

  console.log(props.match.params) // output ==> Object{slug: "news", slug1: "local", slug2: "tour"}

  let taglists = '';

  if(props.match.params.slug1 !== undefined) {
    taglists = props.match.params.slug1
  } else if(props.match.params.slug2 !== undefined) {
    taglists = props.match.params.slug2
  } else {
    taglists = taglists = props.match.params.slug
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Tags</h1>
      Tag Slug: {taglists}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, it works only at *first* and *second*, **not the third**. For example, if I access that full URL, I got this `Tag Slug: local` instead of `Tag Slug: tour`.

How to fix it? Any help will be much appreciated.

**Note**: I've used a simple way (may be for last alternatives) with `props.match.url.split('/').pop()` and it works, but I am still curious if there was a different approach related to my question.

Regards